# ¿Que le falta a mi secuencia SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Veran,debo de listar unos datos básicos para un reporte de ventas por fechas,el problema que tengo es el siguiente, si un cliente en la factura 2 compra 10 articulos me lista los valores de cada articulo y lo que necesito es que me totaliza el valor total de factura independiente de cual sea el detalle de factura.

**Un ejemplo de lo que necesito seria algo como esto:**

```
Numero de factura | nombre cliente | fecha_factura | total

FV - 1            | Pepito Perez   | 2016-02-05    | $10.000

FV - 2            | Pablo botija   | 2016-02-05    | $500.000(asi haya comprado mil artículos, que me los totalice de esta manera)
```

**MI CODIGO**

```
$sql = ejecutar("SELECT 
                    factura.numfactura
                    , factura.vendedor
                    , factura.fechfactura
                    , concat(cliente.nomclie,' ', cliente.apeclie) as nomcliente
                    , formapago.descripcion as nomformapago
                    , (detallefactura.cantarti * detallefactura.valorunidad) as total
                FROM 
                    factura 
                INNER JOIN 
                    cliente ON factura.idclie = cliente.idcliente
                INNER JOIN 
                    formapago ON factura.idformapago = formapago.idformapago
                LEFT JOIN 
                    detallefactura ON factura.idfactura = detallefactura.idfactura
                WHERE
                    factura.fechfactura BETWEEN '".$fechainicial."' AND '".$fechafinal."'",$cnx);
```

Agradeceria si me pueden colaborar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizá te pueda ser util esto, utiliza la función `SUM` y realiza un `GROUP BY` por el número de factura (este último quizá pueda ser opcional, así que prueba sin el y con el, me tomé la molestia de copiar solo el query y poner una fecha de ejemplo para que fuese más legible el código):

```
SELECT 
    factura.numfactura
    , factura.vendedor
    , factura.fechfactura
    , concat(cliente.nomclie,' ', cliente.apeclie) as nomcliente
    , formapago.descripcion as nomformapago
    , SUM((detallefactura.cantarti * detallefactura.valorunidad)) as total
FROM 
    factura 
INNER JOIN 
    cliente ON factura.idclie = cliente.idcliente
INNER JOIN 
    formapago ON factura.idformapago = formapago.idformapago
LEFT JOIN 
    detallefactura ON factura.idfactura = detallefactura.idfactura
WHERE
    factura.fechfactura BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-31-01'
GROUP BY
    factura.numfactura
```

Comment: el `group by` no deberia añadir todos los campos, a excepcion del SUM ¿?

Comment: gracias @Naos aun existe personas generosas... te agradezco, me ha funcionado el query.

Comment: @Daniel podrías indicar si te sirvió con el `ORDER BY` o sin el para aclarar la duda que planteó jolsalazar

Comment: Simplemente con poner el GROUP BY factura.numfactura funciona tal como @Naos lo publico es correcto sin el lo que haria es una suma general de todos los detalles de facturas existen...osea que si hay 5000 mil facturas solo me muestra un ROW con la suma de todas las facturas existentes

Comment: bueno aqui la documentación de mi duda, al parecer no es Ilegal hacer eso :/ https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html